# Nagios: Return code of 255 is out of bounds

Tags: nagios

After adding a new nrpe check the check_nrpe fails to connect although other service checks perform fine. Here is a snapshot of the dashboard with successful checks and the check that fails. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xasia.png) svn_test

```
[root@ip-172-31-15-245 ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H ci2 -c check_svn

connect to address 172.31.3.172 port 5666: Connection refused
```

Comment: first open port 5666 on 172.31.3.172 machine. and then try to check it surly work.

Comment: And make certain there is a check_nrpe command handler on the remote system.

Comment: Did you try the following? sudo nmap -Pn -p 5666 172.31.3.172 What do you see the state? It is more likely that port is not open[closed/filtered]